# DataTables not showing JSON data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, datatable

Here is my `HTML`

```html
    <table id="dt">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>make</th>
                <th>model</th>
                <th>serial</th>
                <th>status</th>
                <th>User</th>
                <th>dept</th>
                <th>location</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            
        </tbody>
        <tfoot></tfoot>
    </table>
```

And here is my `JS`

```js
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
         
        $(document).ready(function() {
            
            $.post("json.php",function(data){
                $('#dt').DataTable( {
                    "aaData": data,
                    "aoColumns": [
                            {"mDataProp": "make"},
                            {"mDataProp": "model"},
                            {"mDataProp": "serial"},
                            {"mDataProp": "status"},
                            {"mDataProp": "user"},
                            {"mDataProp": "dept"},
                            {"mDataProp": "location"}
                        ]
                });
            });
    
        } );
    </script>
```

And here is json.php

```php
    
    $data = Array ();
    $data[] = array("make" => "Hp", "model" => "jhbh", "serial" => "kjkhn", "status" => "active", "user" => "John Doe", "dept" => "Manufacturing Services", "location" => "Bindura");
    $data[] = array("make" => "Dell", "model" => "Vostro", "serial" => "kjkhn", "status" => "active", "user" => "Percy Holdin", "dept" => "Manufacturing Services", "location" => "Kwekwe");
    
    echo json_encode($data,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

I have made an edit to this question, because now I want to get dyanmic data.

Error:

```
DataTables warning: table id=dt - Requested unknown parameter 'make' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4
```

But I havent found anything useful from that help link

Comment: and what of the request and response - do they look correct? (browser developer tools network tab)

Comment: `Here is my HTML` - do you have a `tbody` and a closing `table` tag?

Comment: can you see any errors in console?

Comment: Apparently no, its showing that the XHR was successfuly and no errors

Comment: You must need a <tbody></tbody> to work with DataTable.

Comment: I have it, thats just a snippet, cut off by mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON format should be like this as in this example: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

```
{
    "data": [
        [
            "Hp",
            "jhbh",
            "kjkhn",
            "active",
            "John Doe",
            "Manufacturing Services",
            "Bindura"
        ]
    ]
}
```

Example on how to format json like this in php(well, one way):

```
$data = (object) [
    'data' => [[
        'test',
        'test',
        'test'
    ]]
];
echo json_encode($data);
```

And live example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/632c288c6c743da25e49958c204a8d4e0a936b54

Comment: Thanks man. That worked. How can i format my data like that straight from php?

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works as well, Sorry to keep naggin, what if my data is from an array, check that sandbox link, i have left an example http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b9045b88713feea07f8849b75d51374c4b233adc

Answer (score 0):

you JSON should only be:

```
[
        {
            "make":"Hp",
            "model":"jhbh",
            "serial":"kjkhn",
            "status":"active",
            "user":"John Doe",
            "dept":"Manufacturing Services",
            "location":"Bindura"
        }

    ]
```

Answer (score 0):

You data should like below:

```
{
  "data": [
    [
      "Hp",
      "jhbh",
      "kjkhn",
      "active",
      "John Doe",
      "Manufacturing Services",
      "Bindura"
    ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As others already mentionned in the comments, dataTables need a specific HTML-Structure of the table.

Look at the examples at the Docs:
https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/zero_configuration.html

Table should look like this:

```
<table id="example" class="display">
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Age</th>
        <th>Start date</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT:** Maybe this requirement is outdated. Seems that dataTables can insert the tbody-tag on its own now

And the returned jsonData should have a structure like this
https://datatables.net/examples/ajax/simple.html

```
{
  "data": [
      [
        "Hp",
        "jhbh",
        "kjkhn",
        "active",
        "John Doe",
        "Manufacturing Services",
        "Bindura"
      ]
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting JSON from PHP:

```
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Array was missing some keys, like: 1,2,3,10,122...
Because of missing keys, dataTable plugin won't display data inside table.
So I changed code like so:

```
array_multisort($arr);
echo json_encode($arr);
```

after multisort, keys are reset, and there should not be any missing key.